# Computing the Tukey median

Tags: r, median, tukey

I am trying to compute the data depth of two variables with the following function:

```
library(depth)
x <- data.frame(data$`math score`, data$`reading score`)


depth(1000, x, method = "Tukey", approx = FALSE, eps = 1e-8, ndir = 1000)
```

the first variable after depth is u which stands for Numerical vector whose depth is to be calculated. Dimension has to be the same as that of the observations.
I have 1000 observations however I get the following error message:

```
Error in depth(1000, x, method = "Tukey", approx = FALSE, eps = 1e-08,  : 
  Dimension mismatch between the data and the point u.
```

Does someone know how to solve this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: since we don't have access to your data, could we please have a [mcve]?

Comment: will this do: data(mtcars)?

Comment: @Chiara almost. See if you can replicate the error with `mtcars`. Then you would have a reproducible example that we could work on.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for the function `depth`, it says:

> *u*    Numerical vector whose depth is to be calculated. Dimension has to be the same as that of the observations.

So *u* has to be a point in multidimensional space represented by a vector with *n* components, whereas *x* has to be a matrix or data frame of *m* by *n* components, (*m* rows for *m* points). You are comparing *u* to all the other multidimensional points in the set *x* to find the minimum number of points that could share a half-space with *u*.

Let's create a very example in two dimensional space:

```r
library(depth)

set.seed(100)

x <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(10, -5, 2), rnorm(10, 5, 2)), y = rnorm(20, 0, 2))

plot(x)
```

[image]

The `depth` function calculates the depth of a particular *point* relative to the data. So let's use the origin:

```
u <- data.frame(x = 0, y = 0)
points(u, col = "red", pch = 16)
```

[image]

Naively we might think that the origin here has a depth of 10/20 points (i.e. the most obvious way to partition this dataset is a vertical line through the origin with 10 points on each side, but instead we find:

```
depth(u, x) 
#> [1] 0.35
```

This indicates that there is a half-space including the origin that only contains 0.35 of the points, i.e. 7 points out of 20:

```
depth(u, x) * nrow(x)
#> [1] 7
```

And we can see that visually like this:

```
abline(0, -0.07)
points(x[x$y < (-0.07 * x$x),], col = "blue", pch = 16)
```

[image]

Where we have coloured these 7 points blue.

So it's not clear what result you expect from the `depth` function, but you will need to give it a value of `c(math_score, reading_score)` where `math_score` and `reading_score` are test values for which you want to know the depth.